# dynamic query in mongodb with query builder

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have a search form use to search houses in my web application. Form has the following fields,

```
private String type;
private Long minPrice;
private Long maxPrice;
private Integer minBedRooms;
```

This form is use to search houses when use enter data into all the fields. For example user enter data `"Rent 200 5000 2"` in all fields respectively. My query for this is

```
Query query = new Query(where("type")
            .is(form.getType())
            .and("bedrooms")
            .is(form.getMinBedRooms())
            .andOperator(where("price").lte(form.getMaxPrice()),
                    where("price").gte(form.getMinPrice())));
```

NOW when i leave one of the above fields empty, it returns `0` results. For example when `maxPrice` is null, it returns `0` results. My question is how should i write the above query so that it can igone the null values. For example, i leave the `maxPrice` and `minBedRooms` fields empty the it will search data based on the `type` and `minPrice`

I am using spring 4. and spring data with mongoDB

I have been stuck with this for two days, I shall be very thankful for any kind of help.
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following for is equivalent, but adding the logic tests around it

```java
  Query query = new Query();

  if (form.getType() != null) {
      query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("type")
        .is(form.getType());
  }

  if (form.getMinBedrooms() != 0) {
        query.addCriteira(Criteria.where("bedrooms")
        .is(form.getMinBedRooms())
  }
```

And so on. So just work with the Query object and add your conditions.